# Round amounts internationalized

Tags: java

Rounding amounts in Germany we must use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`.

- [The rule is called "Kaufmännisches Runden"](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rundung&redirect=no#Kaufm.C3.A4nnisches_Runden)

Is there any rounding-function for amounts who accepts the Locale in Java?

This is not improbably since `toUpperCase` respects the Locale too.

Comment: "we must use Math.round instead of Math.floor" Why?

Comment: Rounding method is not language or culture dependent.

Comment: Using Math.round over Math.floor might depend on the country for the software that you're writing, but it most certainly doesn't depend on what country you're in *in general*.  My advise is to make a factory that returns a lambda function (if you're using Java 8) based on Locale.

Comment: Rounding is different from truncating. Maybe different rounding modes are of different popularity in different countries, but I've never heard of anyone who says "round" to mean "truncate" (which is what `floor` does, really).

Comment: @BenAaronson Updated question, see the link.

Comment: @JacquesB You are right. But how to round is Country and Area depend, Country is Germany and Area is Commercial.

Comment: @PeterRader The answer to your immediate question is no, there isn't a way to do this using standard java libraries.  Would you prefer an answer explaining best approach to implementing one yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working at three different places in one ***state*** within the US, I've encountered three different ways of rounding numbers in different applications. This isn't locale dependent - its industry dependent (finance, retail, science all round differently for different reasons).

- Reporting to the finance department (from my retail experience) wanted things rounded up (`HALF_UP`) always. Makes it consistent and easy to explain.
- Retail wanted it rounded always in the customer's favor (this is not a default rounding mode). You may lose a penny here or there, but it reduced the likelihood of a person arguing with the front end manager about an incorrect receipt (which would cost ***much*** more than a penny)
- Science used `HALF_EVEN` to avoid systematic biasing of the data (half the time `x.5` gets rounded up, half the time it gets rounded down - so `1.5` gets rounded to `2`, and `2.5` also gets rounded to `2` (more on this on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) which points out this is sometimes known as "bankers' rounding")).

> A `Locale` object represents a specific geographical, political, or cultural region.

(From the javadocs for [java.util.Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html))

So no.  There is no local association for rounding. Not everyone in a given locale always rounds the same way. It depends on the application - not the geographical, political or cultural grouping.

Comment: If it depends the locale i could transfer a half cent one million times and earn 10k... i remember a movie about this hack.

Comment: @PeterRader if you are dealing with money different things apply than if you are dealing with science papers. That distinction isn't covered in `java.util.Locale`.

Answer (score -1):

"Kaufmännisches Runden" seem to just be the German name for "Bankers rounding". It is not something culture specific.

See the various rounding modes supported here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Putting part of that wikipedia page through google translate I get:  "If the figure at the first dropped decimal place is a 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 or 4 , then rounded.
    If the figure at the first dropped decimal place a 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 or 9 , then it is rounded up ." So not even banker's rounding. Just round less than half down, half or more up.

Comment: So the answer is no?  It isn't implemented in Java standard libraries?